# about oracle/sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a table:

```
create table emp; (
   emp_id number(10) 
   emp_name varchar2(20)
 , address varchar2(50);
   )
```

and a error is present in line 3, after `emp_id number(10)` - a comma is missing. I can't go back or directly to that line.

I have to make new table or write it again. My question is how can we remove that error without writing it again or without using copy/paste. Can we use an edit command/query or is there a query whereby we can go directly to the place where the error occurs?

Comment: 1) You navigate to the place in whatever editor/GUI you're using by whatever means you want to use and then you correct your syntax... you also have two random semi-colons... OR 2) you write it correctly the first time.

Comment: Or 3) you get one of your minions, sorry valued colleagues, to create the table for you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are different commands available which allows you to edit the last (wrongly)entered SQL query and reexecute it.

```
SQL> create table emp(
  2  emp_id number(10)
  3  emp_name varchar2(20)
  4  , address varchar2(50));
emp_name varchar2(20)
*
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Here, I made mistake, and forget entering comma after 2nd line. I can correct it as below

```
SQL> list 2
  2* emp_id number(10)
SQL> append ,
  2* emp_id number(10),
SQL> run
  1  create table emp(
  2  emp_id number(10),
  3  emp_name varchar2(20)
  4* , address varchar2(50))

Table created.

SQL>
```

You can get more information for all these commands here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a82950/ch3.htm

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon after create table emp and just put a comma after emp_id number(10). Also remove the simicolon after address varchar2(50) and place it at the end